# Dynamically Generate List From Dataframe Elements (dynamic categories)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

folks-

I am trying to generate a `list` in R where each element of the `list` represents a disease category, and within each element is a vector of corresponding patient ids. In order to do this, I would like to utilize relationships defined in an existing `data.frame`.

```
diseaseTbl <- data.frame(PatientId = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,1,2,3,7,8,9,10),
                        DiseaseCat = c(rep('Obesity',6),rep('Diabetes',3),rep('Hypertension',7)))
```

Here's my approach to generate the `list` I'm looking for- which is admittedly not ideal:

```
myList = list(
                  Obesity=diseaseTbl[which(diseaseTbl$DiseaseCat == 'Obesity'),]$PatientId,
                  Diabetes=diseaseTbl[which(diseaseTbl$DiseaseCat == 'Diabetes'),]$PatientId,
                  Hypertension=diseaseTbl[which(diseaseTbl$DiseaseCat == 'Hypertension'),]$PatientId
            )
```

This is a small scale example- whereas my live data is filled with 30+ disease categories. I would like a way to dynamically generate this `list` so that I can adapt dynamically to changing disease categories (add/remove). Is there a more elegant solution out there? I assume that I will be embarrassed by how easy this is for somebody to figure out. Thank you!

Comment: How about: `split(diseaseTbl$PatientId, diseaseTbl$DiseaseCat)`?

Comment: Yikes. Yep, it was that easy, huh? Thank you.